# AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view

I have one form which reads data from web api, bellow dates I have two radio buttons All and Excluded, when Excluded is checked I want to show only records that have Check = 1 in it. I hope you understand me, is there any easy way to solve this in the view ? some ng-if condition or something like that.

Comment: What do you have tried? Take a look in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ng-show/ng-hide property (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) in your record. It would look something like:

```
<div ng-hide="exluded && check!=1">Your record</div>
```

The radio button should have as ng-model the excluded variable.

With this what you would achieve is tho show all the records always, except when the variable excluded is set to true and the check variable is not 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter pipe in your ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="record in records | filter: matches">
   {{record.name}}
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9j76amg/1/) that uses that approach.